# Whether the given series is convergent or divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

It is given that:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{\frac{3}{2}+n}}$$
>
> My Attempt: 
>   Since there is a power of $n$ involved, I tried root test. It turns out that lim $n$ tending to infinity
>   $|a_{n}|^{1/n}=1$. So, the test is inconclusive.

Then I went for ratio test, but that didn't help me much. I am unable to determine whether the series is convergent or divergent.

Any help is appreciated.Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{\frac{3}{2}+n}}=\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}\to 0$$

Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{\frac{3}{2}+n}}$ converges by limit comparison test with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ since

$$\frac{a_n}{\frac1{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\to e$$

Comment: $a_n\to 0$ means indeed that the sequence is convergent to $0$

Comment: @HeavyMetaL When $a_n \to L\in \mathbb R$ we say that $a_n$ converges. The definition allows the case $L=0$.

Comment: But this is true for sequences. But in series, if $a_{n}$ tends to zero, that doesn't imply that  the series converges.

Comment: @HeavyMetaL Yes of course! But here are you dealing with sequence or with a series?

Comment: I am sorry for the above confusion. I have edited my question, and the question is about the series is convergent or not.

Comment: @HeavyMetaL Ah ok I update the answer then!

Comment: Thankyou @gimusi. And sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n=(1+\frac 1 n)^{n}\frac 1 {n^{3/2}} \to (e)(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}} \to e \times 0=0$